# Building/Dissecting complicated mulit-layered scapy packet

Tags: python, scapy

I am working on write scapy packets to handle many of the DMTF manageability packets.  Have been successful thus far in doing most of them.  However I have now come to Redfish over PLDM in this spec: https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0218_1.0.0.pdf

Specifically I am trying to figure out how to properly model the Dictionary Binary Format table in section 7.2.3.2. The part that is troubling me is that this table contains basically an array of Packets that describe among other things offsets and lengths of stings that are at the end of the packet.  So there will be a number of these Packets (which I would use a `PacketListField` for), followed by a list of strings that they describe.  So there are 'N' of these Packets/Headers followed by 'N' variable length strings of which those headers contain the length and the offset of where the string begins.

I can dissect all this manually, but was hoping to use `FieldLenField` and `StrLenFields` to do this; however I am unable to figure out a slick way of doing this.  Only been playing with Scapy for a few weeks, so I am hoping somebody with more experience could help me out and provide some direction.

If the name string were part of the Dictionary Entry, I would do something like the following, however since it is not, I'm not sure how to link the `FieldLenField` to the `StrLenField`.

```
class beJtupleF(Packet)
    name = "beJtupleF"
    fields_desc = [
        BitEnumField("PrincipleDataType",0,4,BEJFormatCodes),
        BitField("reserved_flag",0,1),
        BitField("nullable_property",0,1),
        BitField("read_only",0,1),
        BitField("deferred_binding",0,1)
    ]


class DictionaryEntry(Packet):
    name = "Dictionary Entry"
    fields_desc = [
        PacketField("Format",beJtupleF(),beJtupleF),
        ShortField("SequenceNumber",0),
        ShortField("ChildPointerOffset",0),
        ShortField("ChildCount",0),
        ByteField("NameLength",0)
        FieldLenField("NameLength",None,"Name","B"),    # length of 'Name'
        ShortField("NameOffset",0) # Not sure how to fill this one in automatically either :-)
        StrLenField("Name","",length_from = lambda pkt: pkt.NameLength), # Variable len Name
    ]
```